# Refactoring nested rescue statements

Tags: ruby, rescue

Rescue statement serves well when it comes to successive filtering of different errors:

```
o = Object.new
begin
  o.foo
rescue ArgumentError
  puts "Object o does define #foo, but you got the argument number wrong!"
rescue NoMethodError
  puts "Object o does not respond to #foo!"
else
  puts "That's right!"
end
```

But when it comes to rescuing the *same* error with different parameters, this is what I use in my code:

```
o = Object.new
begin
  o.foo
rescue NoMethodError
  begin
    o.bar
  rescue NoMethodError
    begin
      o.quux
    rescue NoMethodError
      warn "Object o responds not to basic methods!"
    end
  end
end
```

Needless to say, I don't like it. Isn't there a more clever way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def send_messages_maybe(object, messages, *parameters)
  object.send(messages.first, *parameters)
rescue NoMethodError
  messages = messages[1..-1]
  if messages.empty?
    warn "Object does not respond to basic methods!"
  else
    retry
  end
end

module Quux
  def quux(*args)
    puts "quux method called with #{args.inspect}"
  end
end

messages = %i{foo bar quux}
send_messages_maybe(Object.new, messages)
send_messages_maybe(Object.new.extend(Quux), messages, 10, :hello, 'world')
```

Output:

```
Object does not respond to basic methods!
quux method called with [10, :hello, "world"]
```

This works with objects that don't have a `#respond_to_missing?` method defined, which is very common --- most of the code I've seen that uses `#method_missing` falls into this category.

Comment: +1, thanks for reminding me of `def ... rescue ... end` syntax and providing an example of `retry` use.

Answer (score 2):

Probably this don't answer your question, but in this case I'd ask to `o` if it `responds_to?` the method I want to call, before calling it:

```
method = [:foo, :bar, :baz].find { |m| o.respond_to?(m) }
if method
  o.public_send(method)
else
  warn "Object o responds not to basic methods!"
end
```

Comment: No, it does not. Object `o` in reality searches a BibTeX file and if it fails tries another file or another search until it runs out of options. So `#respond_to?` does not help.